# Reviews from site duplicate

Tags: scrapy

I am scraping reviews from a website and these reviews tend to duplicate. The issue I am facing is with the mitatigation of duplicates and I am thinking my xpath may be an issue but I cannot solve this.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import JsonRequest
import pandas as pd


class CruisesItems(scrapy.Item):
    user_rating = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    user = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    location = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    title = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    reviews = Field(output_processor = Join())


class CruisesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cruises_reviews'
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Cruise_Review-d15691240-Reviews-AmaWaterways_AmaSerena']


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback = self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.xpath("//div[@class='ui_column is-12-desktop is-12-tablet is-12-mobile cEMcR']/div[2]//div")
        for reviews in container:
            loader = ItemLoader(CruisesItems(), selector = reviews)
            loader.add_xpath('user_rating', "//div[@class='eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC']//div[@class='emWez F1']/span/@class")
            loader.add_xpath('user', "(//div[@class='eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC']//div[@class='xMxrO']//div[@class='bcaHz']//span//text())[position() mod 2=1]")
            loader.add_xpath('location',"(//div[@class='eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC']//div[@class='xMxrO']//div[@class='BZmsN']//span//text())[position() mod 5=1]")
            loader.add_xpath('title', ".//div[@class='eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC']//div[@class='fpMxB MC _S b S6 H5 _a']//text()")
            loader.add_xpath('reviews', "//div[@class='eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC']//div[@class='pIRBV _T']//span//text()")
            yield loader.load_item()
        
process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEEDS':{
            'cruise_reviews.jl':{
                'format':'jsonlines'
            }
        }
    }
)
process.crawl(CruisesSpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relative xpath.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import JsonRequest
import pandas as pd


class CruisesItems(scrapy.Item):
    user_rating = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    user = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    location = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    title = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    reviews = Field(output_processor = Join())


class CruisesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cruises_reviews'
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Cruise_Review-d15691240-Reviews-AmaWaterways_AmaSerena']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.5
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # container = response.xpath("//div[@class='ui_column is-12-desktop is-12-tablet is-12-mobile cEMcR']/div[2]//div")
        container = response.xpath('//div[@id="ship_reviews"]//div[@class="eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC"]')
        for reviews in container:
            loader = ItemLoader(CruisesItems(), selector=reviews)
            loader.add_xpath('user_rating', ".//div[@class='emWez F1']/span/@class")
            loader.add_xpath('user', "(.//div[@class='xMxrO']//div[@class='bcaHz']//span//text())[position() mod 2=1]")
            loader.add_xpath('location', "(//div[@class='xMxrO']//div[@class='BZmsN']//span//text())[position() mod 5=1]")
            loader.add_xpath('title', ".//div[@class='fpMxB MC _S b S6 H5 _a']//text()")
            loader.add_xpath('reviews', ".//div[@class='pIRBV _T']//span//text()")
            yield loader.load_item()


process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings = {
        'FEEDS':{
            'cruise_reviews.jl':{
                'format':'jsonlines'
            }
        }
    }
)
process.crawl(CruisesSpider)
process.start()
```

Notice that I moved `//div[@class="eVykL Gi z cPeBe MD cwpFC"]` to the container because it's in all the item's xpaths.